# UTM variables tracking issue using php

Tags: php, wordpress, analytics, utm

I need help to clarify utm tracking between php and google analytics (g4). My client wanted me to build a tracking dashboard for UTM variables using php. Site running on WordPress CMS.

I simply used PHP $_GET HTTP GET variables to catch these parameters and store they in DB:

```
$utm_source = ( isset($_GET['utm_source']) ) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['utm_source']) : '';
$utm_source = (!empty($utm_source)) ? $utm_source : 'no source';
//further saving to the database
```

For details debugging I also record all incoming GET variables in txt file on the wordpress init hook :

```
add_action( 'init', 'init_tracking_all_gets_variables' );
function init_tracking_all_gets_variables() {
    $fp   = fopen('gets_variables.txt', 'a');
    $time = current_time("D M d, Y H:i:s");
    $string  = '==================================' . "\n";
    $string .= $time . "\n";
    $string .= serialize($_GET) . "\n";
    fwrite($fp, $string);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

So seems like this code works as I expected, we see incoming utm tags. But in G4 sometimes somehow we see weird session source / medium like: ecosia.org / organic, yahoo / organic,  posten / valgfritt, l.facebook.com / referral and etc with a very small number of user visits. And they never track on the my tracking dashboard and even in my gets_variables.txt file which should writes absolutely all incoming get variables to the site. Where could be the problem?

Comment: Those are just additional sources, not related to UTM at all. You might be able to inspect the referal header

Comment: But why then they showed in g4 as session source? Referal header should contain only url, isn't?

Comment: Google looks at the URL, determines the domain, and buckets them together.